# Website spans entire page, I don't want it to

Tags: html, css, containers, wrapper, responsive

I am developing a website and I want to put it in a wrapper or container so I can limit to let's say 1000px and not the entire webpage.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div class="wrap">
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>

<div class="header">
  <h1>Family Restaurant</h1>
</div>

<div class="row">

<div class="col-3 menu">
  <ul>
    <li>The Flight</li>
    <li>The City</li>
    <li>The Island</li>
    <li>The Food</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="col-3">
  <h1>The City</h1>
  <p>Chania is the capital of the Chania region on the island of Crete. The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.</p>
</div>
<div class="col-3">
  <h1>The City</h1>
  <p>Chania is the capital of the Chania region on the island of Crete. The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.</p>
</div>

<div class="col-3 right">
  <div class="aside">
    <h2>What?</h2>
    <p>Chania is a city on the island of Crete.</p>
    <h2>Where?</h2>
    <p>Crete is a Greek island in the Mediterranean Sea.</p>

  </div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="row">


<div class="col-3">
  <h1>The City</h1>
  <p>Chania is the capital of the Chania region on the island of Crete. The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.</p>
</div>
<div class="col-3">
  <h1>The City</h1>
  <p>Chania is the capital of the Chania region on the island of Crete. The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.</p>
</div>
<div class="col-3">
  <h1>The City</h1>
  <p>Chania is the capital of the Chania region on the island of Crete. The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.</p>
</div>
<div class="col-3">
  <h1>The City</h1>
  <p>Chania is the capital of the Chania region on the island of Crete. The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.</p>
</div>

</div>


<div class="row">
<div class="col-12">
  <h1>The City</h1>
  <p>Chania is the capital of the Chania region on the island of Crete. The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-6">
  <h1>The City</h1>
  <p>Chania is the capital of the Chania region on the island of Crete. The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.</p>
</div>
<div class="col-6">
  <h1>The City</h1>
  <p>Chania is the capital of the Chania region on the island of Crete. The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how the content respond to the resizing.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
}
html {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans", sans-serif;
}
.header {
    height:auto;
    background-color: #9933cc;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 5px;
}
.menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.menu li {
    padding: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    background-color: #33b5e5;
    color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}
.menu li:hover {
    background-color: #0099cc;
}
.aside {
    background-color: #33b5e5;
    padding: 15px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}
.footer {
    background-color: #0099cc;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 15px;
}
/* For desktop: */
.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}
.col-50 {width: 50%;}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    /* For mobile phones: */
    [class*="col-"] {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

I added a wrapper class and styled it but it doesn't seem to be working.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting everything between the `body` open and close tags in the following.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/x213jqvs/)

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
...
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper{
    max-width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto; /* makes your content centered horizontally */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply apply the css for wrapper like below.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 400px; //Edit to 1000px
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.section {
 background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="section">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
</div>
```